# Pandas Moving Average

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I am trying to plot the moving average for a rolling window of 30 days on a column of a Quandl dataset that I have added as a column of a pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like: [image]

How do I firstly compute the moving average, and after that, how do I plot it in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in Pandas DataFrame function.

1.To compute:

To compute moving average - e.g. 20 Days (I can see you're using daily data/business days)

```
YourDataFrame['Instrument_name'].rolling(20).mean()
```

2.To Plot:

Pandas also provide simple plotting functionality. You can use it to plot both charts.

```
YourDataFrame['Instrument_name'].plot() 
YourDataFrame['Instrument_name'].rolling(20).mean().plot()
```

['Instrument_name']  --> this is your column name, for example ['value_gold']